# jquery change css of every fourth item?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I was wondering if it was possible for jquery to change the css of every 4th item (div) inside another div? I've had a look around but can't seem to get it working..

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

or the [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)